# How to add sequlize.js transactions in a async function

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

So far I didn't add transactions to my project. Now I'm consider my self to upgrade to that level.

If I need to update master table, details table and the logs table I would do something like this.

```
export async function create(req,res,next){
    try{

    const add_to_master_table = await db.Inovice_master.create();

    const add_to_detail_table = await db.Invoice_detail.create();

    const add_to_user_logs = await db.User_logs.create();

    res.sendStatus(200);

    }catch(error){
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
}
```

In sequlize documentation transaction is something like this

```js
return sequelize.transaction(function (t) {

  // chain all your queries here. make sure you return them.
  return User.create({
    firstName: 'Abraham',
    lastName: 'Lincoln'
  }, {transaction: t}).then(function (user) {
    return user.setShooter({
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Boothe'
    }, {transaction: t});
  });

}).then(function (result) {
  // Transaction has been committed
  // result is whatever the result of the promise chain returned to the transaction callback
}).catch(function (err) {
  // Transaction has been rolled back
  // err is whatever rejected the promise chain returned to the transaction callback
});
```

So my question is how do I embed transactions to my code with out leaving the async / await fashion.

Anyhelp!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write down it in this way.

```
return sequelize.transaction(async (t) =>  {

  let user = await User.create({firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Lincoln'}, { transaction: t })
  user = await user.setShooter({ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Boothe'}, { transaction: t });
  return user
})
```

I prefer to user CLS mechanism for Transaction passing you also don't have to pass transactions to each query.

[Automatically pass transactions to all queries](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/transactions.html)

Comment: A word of warning: The CLS mechanism doesn't work for async/await transactions in Sequelize 3.  I hope it's fixed in Sequelize 5, but I haven't tried it out yet.